# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

It's my first time asking question here :) I'm a beginner with Django and I've been stuck on my edit_booking method for days, I don't even know what I'm doing wrong anymore...
I'm making a booking system and I'm getting a `"TypeError at /edit-booking/6 __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'"`. I've been trying a lot of things to make editing the exact booking possible, but they only cause more errors...

Views:

```
class EditBooking(DetailView):

    def __init__(self):    
        template_name = 'edit-profile.html'        
        initial = {}

    @login_required
    def edit_booking(request, id):
        booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, id=id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BookingForm(request.POST, instance=booking)
            customer_data = UserProfile.objects.all()
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.customer_data = customer_data
                instance.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your booking has been updated!')
            else:
                return messages.error(request, form.errors)
        else:
            form = BookingForm(initial={
                'booking_date': booking.booking_date,
                'booking_time': booking.booking_time,
                'table_size': booking.table_size,
                'additional_info': booking.additional_info,
            })
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Templates:

profile.html button triggering edit page:

```
<a href="{% url 'editbooking' id=booking.id %}" aria-label="edit booking">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-brown px-5">Edit</button>
</a>
```

edit_booking.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'editbooking' id=booking.id %}" 
class="col-6">                                  
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
</form>
```

Urls:

```
path('edit-booking/<int:id>', views.EditBooking, name='editbooking'),
```

Models:

```
class Booking(models.Model):

    booking_customer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    booking_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    booking_time = models.CharField(choices=TIME_SLOTS, default='8:00 - 8:30', max_length=50)
    table_size = models.CharField(choices=TABLE_SIZE, default='1', max_length=50)
    additional_info = models.TextField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    booked_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_confirmed = models.CharField(choices=CONFIRMATION, default='Awaiting confirmation', max_length=50)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=70, unique=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["booked_on"]
        

    def __str__(self):

        return f'Booking for {self.booking_date} at {self.booking_time} was booked on {self.booked_on} and currently has a status: {self.is_confirmed}'
```

Forms:

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    """ 
    Provides necessary fields to the booking form for customers
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Crispy form helpers
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'        
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-secondary btn-brown mb-4 mx-auto px-5'))        

    # Provides a date widget to the form 
    booking_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date', 'value': datetime.date.today}), required=False)
    booking_time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TIME_SLOTS, required=False)
    table_size = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TABLE_SIZE, required=False)
    additional_info = forms.CharField(max_length=400, widget=SummernoteWidget(), required=False)
    booked_on = forms.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.datetime.now, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required = False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=70, unique=True, populate_from=lambda instance: instance.title,
                         unique_with=['booked_on', 'booking_date'],
                         slugify=lambda value: value.replace(' ','-')) 


    # Provides a model to pull the fields from
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['booking_date', 'booking_time', 'table_size', 'additional_info']
        read_only = ['booked_on', 'slug']


    # Prevents booking dates in the past
    def save_booking(self, *args, **kwargs):

        data = self.cleaned_data
        if data.get('booking_date') < datetime.date.today():        
            raise ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
        else:
            super(Booking, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I was trying to use slug, pk and id to get the exact booking, I changed the urls and templates to display the id, used Booking.objects.get() and swapped it in the end with get_object_or_404, getting rid of **init**  etc... I've been searching through similar questions here, but none of the solutions that i've tried worked for me really :(

Comment: There are several problems here, one is you don't use `.as_view()`, but you also create a lot of boilerplate logic. For example `edit_booking(..)` will never be triggered.

Comment: I was trying to use .as_view(), but it was throwing another error

Comment: Edited: I forgot to include my other template that has an 'edit' button :) @willeM_VanOnsem would you be able to tell me what are other several problems? I'm feeling very lost and at this point I feel that I need a direct point what to fix :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here. First of all, you register a class-based view with `.as_view()` which essentially wraps the class into a function that handles requests, so:

```
path('edit-booking/<int:id>', views.EditBooking.as_view(), name='editbooking'),
```

Likely you now get an error about the `template_name` and the model not being specified, which makes sense: you didn't define it, and tried to define it in the constructor. Your view also looks a lot like an [**`UpdateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), not that much a `DetailView`. You can see an `UpdateView` as a `DetailView`, but with a form to allow editing. This will also populate the form already with the instance in the GET request, which probably makes it more convenient.

We can use the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin)
and [**`SuccessMessageMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin) to check if the user has logged in and also already encode a message when the item was successful:

What makes not much sense is the `.customer_data = customer_data`: you don't store that in your model object. You can set the `.booking_customer` with the `UserProfile` of the logged in user, but that depends on the `UserProfile` model, so you probably have to revise the `form_valid()` method overload.

Finally a successful POST request normally results in a redirect to some path, you set that by the `success_url`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic import UpdateView


class EditBooking(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Booking
    form_class = BookingForm
    template_name = 'edit-profile.html'
    success_message = 'Thank you! Your booking has been updated!'
    success_url = '/path/to/some/view'

    # no __init__

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.booking_customer = UserProfile.objects.get(
            user=self.request.user
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)
```